# How to stop old instance from ELB in ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, elastic-load-balancer

I have playbook which creates and add instance to Load balancer, what is the way I can remove/stop old instance already assigned to ELB, I want to make sure that we stop the old instance first and then new 1s are added or vice verse.
I am using AWS ELB and EC2 instance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, share your playbook code. [ec2_elb](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_elb_module.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that might help you. Once you have the `instance id` then you can do whatever you want, I am just removing it from the ELB but you can use the `ec2` module to remove it.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   - name: Get the facts about the ELB
     ec2_elb_facts:
       names: rbgeek-dev-web-elb
       region: "eu-west-1"
     register: elb_facts

   - name: Instance(s) ID that are currently register to the ELB
     debug:
       msg: "{{ elb_facts.elbs.0.instances }}"

   - name: Tag the Old instances as zombie
     ec2_tag:
       resource: "{{ item }}"
       region: "eu-west-1"
       state: present
       tags:
         Instance_Status: "zombie"
     with_items: "{{ elb_facts.elbs.0.instances }}"

   - name: Refresh the ec2.py cache
     shell: ./inventory/ec2.py --refresh-cache
     changed_when: no

   - name: Refresh inventory
     meta: refresh_inventory


# must check this step with ec2_remote_facts_module.html ##http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_remote_facts_module.html
- hosts: tag_Instance_Status_zombie
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Get the facts about the zombie instances
      ec2_facts:
    - name: remove instance by instance id
      ec2:
        state: absent
        region: "eu-west-1"
        instance_ids: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
        wait: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```